# What is the difference between 'EVERY TIME' and 'EVERY SINGLE TIME'

Tags: difference, emphasis

I just heard this in conversation among my friends. Is there in difference between to say *every time* and *every single time*.

Answer (score 4):

There's not really any difference in meaning, only in emphasis.

When you add the word *single*, you are intensifying the emotion with which something is said, whether that be frustration (as in the first example) or elation (as in the latter):

> Every time we plan a picnic, it rains.
>   Every single time we plan a picnic, it rains.
>
> Every time I go on a date with Carol, I don't want the night to end.
>   Every single time I go on a date with Carol, I don't want the night to end.

Comment: My gut feeling is that it's more often used as a negative than a positive, but I don't know how to test this.

Comment: @Andrew -  I concur. As I was writing my answer, I noticed it was much easier to think of usages where the saying is being used in anger or frustration.

Answer (score 1):

In your usage

> single

is used as an intensifier to bring attention to how often *something* happens.

It is the same as saying

> **Each and every time** we plan picnic, it rains.
>   *Whenever we want to have a picnic it rains.*

Strictly speaking, it probably doesn't rain when you are **planning** a picnic, but when you are *trying to picnic*.

> **Each and every time** we want to picnic, it rains.
>   **Whenever** we sit down to have a picnic, it rains.